# Link to HTML-File on Raspberry Pi running openHAB

Tags: networking, remote, html5, openhab

On the Raspberry Pi, I have an html-file which I can view when directly logged into the Raspberry Pi. The page is shown on a display that is directly connected to the Raspberry Pi.

Now I want to invoke that file using Firefox or Edge on my PC. I've tried a lot of combinations in the address line of the browser, none of them worked.

For example:
http://192.168.178.200/file:///opt/openhab/configurations/sitemaps/dashboard.html
or
http://192.168.178.200:8080/opt/openhab/configurations/sitemaps/dashboard.html

IP-address of the Raspberry Pi: `192.168.178.200`
Port which is used by the openHAB web server: `8080`
Path to the html-file: `/opt/openhab/configurations/sitemaps`
Name of the html-file: `dashboard.html`

Please help me to create an address line to invoke that html-file.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello, openHab is not a webserver per-se but this might help: https://www.openhab.org/docs/configuration/ui/classic/#accessing-sitemaps. In your case something like http://192.168.178.200:8080/classicui might get you started...

Comment: Thank, I'll have a look at it.
On the Raspberry I just use this:
file:///opt/openhab/configurations/sitemaps/dashboard.html

Comment: The problem seems to be that I don't want to access a sitemap but just an html-file which is not directly linked to openHab.

Comment: OK, in that case you'll need to work out the _document root_ for the openHAB webserver and use the URL that's relative to that. It might well be that you'll not be able to navigate to it this way (i.e. it's not being served by the webserver) in which case you'll have to install a new webserver that does or change the openHAB settings somehow.

Comment: Hello and welcome to this community. I just read these comments but answered. You should change the title and body of the question. It's not about linking/redirecting a web page, as @RogerJones said, it's related to OpenHAB!

Comment: Open the OpenHAB config file and change `OPENHAB_HTTP_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1` to `OPENHAB_HTTP_ADDRESS=192.168.178.20` if the PC's IP address is `192.168.178.20`. If you don't want to make a limitation, comment it `#OPENHAB_HTTP_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it by a simple package named `apache`. It's a powerful web server, however, you can accomplish what you said by it.

**1.** Install Apache:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

**2.** Start the service:

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

**3.** Open the browser of the Raspberry Pi and open `http://localhost/` address by a browser. You'll something like the picture below:

[image]

Next, do it by another host/PC on the network. Note that in this case, you need to open `http://raspberrypi.local`, `http://raspberrypi` or `http://[Raspberrypi's-IP-Address]`.

**4.** Put your `.html` files in the `/var/www/html/` directory. As an example, I had a folder named "khar" and in this folder, I had two files, `gav.html` and `sag.html`.

**4.1.** Move/copy folder to the apache's directory:

```
cp -r khar /var/www/html/
```

**4.2.** Now, I can open `.html` files by opening `http://raspberrypi/gav.html` or `http://raspberrypi/sag.html` in the browser.

If you want this service start at startup, do it:

```
sudo systemctl enable apache2
```

---

**UPDATE:**
It's not about linking/redirecting a web page, as @RogerJones said, it's related to OpenHAB!

Open the OpenHAB config file and change `OPENHAB_HTTP_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1` to `OPENHAB_HTTP_ADDRESS=192.168.178.20` if the PC's IP address is `192.168.178.20`.
If you don't want to make a limitation, comment it `#OPENHAB_HTTP_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1`.